# Get dates by month in C# Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, datetime, visual-studio-2012

The following code displays a list of appointments scheduled for a specific date in my windows phone 7 app

```
private void DisplayAppointmentsForDate(DateTime date)
{

    appointmentsSource.FetchData(date, date.AddDays(1));
    this.AppointmentsList.ItemsSource = appointmentsSource.GetAppointments((IAppointment appointment) =>
    {
        DateTime currentAppointmentStart = appointment.StartDate;
        DateTime currentAppointmentEnd = appointment.EndDate;
        DateTime requiredAppointmentsStartDate = date.Date;
        DateTime requiredAppointmentsEndDate = date.Date.AddDays(1);


        if (requiredAppointmentsEndDate > currentAppointmentStart && requiredAppointmentsStartDate < currentAppointmentEnd)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    });
}

private void RadCalendar_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    if (e.NewValue == null)
    {
        this.AppointmentsList.ItemsSource = null;
        return;
    }
    DisplayAppointmentsForDate((e.NewValue as DateTime?).Value);
}
```

But this shows the appointments scheduled for a specific date. EG. If 23/09/2013 is selected on the calendar, then the list would display all the appointments on that day.

I want to change this so that the list displays all appointments for a particular month. EG. If the calendar is on the month of July 2013, the the list should show all appointments in that month.

The Start and End Dates are all set to DateTime type with values such as 23/09/2013 12:01PM, and this is how it is used to get list of apps.

I've tried using `appointmentsSource.FetchData(date.Month, date.AddDays(1));`, but it doesn't work.

How do I do this?

Comment: What have you already tried? In particular, your `FetchData` call looks like it does all you need it to, so long as you give the start of the one month and the start of the following month...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the method FetchData takes a "start date" parameter and an "end date parameter", in which case, you just need to get the first date of the current month and the last date of the current month

```
        var currentDate = DateTime.Now; // Or whatever date you want to displa
        var startDate = new DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month, 1);
        var endDate = new DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month));

        appointmentsSource.FetchData(startDate, endDate);
```

if your FetchData takes a month parameter and the number of days, then

```
 appointmentsSource.FetchData(currentDate.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month));
```

we really need to see the "FetchData" method to be able to provide you with a definitive answer